# Inverse matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Show that if $A^2=O$ then $A$ is singular, but $I−A$ is nonsingular and $(I−A)^{-1}=I+A$.

What I have tiedy:
$(I-A)*(I+A)=I-A+A-A^2$

$=I-A^2$

$=I-0$    since A^2=0

$=I$

Therefore $I-A$ is nonsingular.

I am not sure if is complete and correct.

Comment: Yes, everything works.

Comment: Your proof of the second part is the fine. For the first part, make use of the multiplicative property of the determinant.

Comment: Is the frst part you said something like this: A*A=A^2

Comment: You don't need determinants here. If $Ax=0$ for all $x$, then clearly $A$ is singular. If not, then choose $x$ so that $Ax \neq 0$. Then $A (Ax) = 0$, hence $A$ is singular.

Comment: If $A$ were invertible, multiplying both sides of $A^2 = 0$ by $A^{-1}$ would yield $A = 0$.

Comment: See also: [If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^2=0$, is $A+I_{n}$ invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^2 = O \implies \det(A)\det(A) = \det(A^2) = 0$ So $\det(A) = 0$ and $A$ is singular.

$(I-A)(I + A) = I + A - A - A^2 = I$ the same is true for $(I+A)(I-A)$ so $I - A$ is invertible with inverse $I + A$.