# Say $A^2 = 0$. Prove that for every real number $a$, the matrix $I + a A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> Say $A^2 = 0$. Prove that for every real number $a$, the matrix $I + a A$ is invertible.

I need some help with this question.

Comment: Duplicate, in a particular case, of the recent question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2261845)

Comment: See also: [If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^2=0$, is $A+I_{n}$ invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19538)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that:$$(I + aA)(I - aA) = I - a^2A^2 = I$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's have $v\in\ker(I+aA)$

Then $(I+aA)v=v+aAv=0$

We multiply by $A$ again to get $Av+aA^2v=Av+0=0$

But then $v+aAv=v+0=0$

> So $\ker(I+aA)=\{0\}$

Comment: Kernels related to transformations, I don't need to say ker(I+a[T]B) where B is some base of R^n?

Comment: It is common to write $\ker(M)$ for a matrix instead of $\ker(f)$ where $f$ is the linear map associated to $f(\vec x)=M\vec x$. A matrix is implicitly always associated to a linear application.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues of $I+aA$ are non-zero numbers. So it is invertible.

Comment: How do you prove that?

Comment: Eigenvalues of $aA$ are all zeros; because $A$ is nilpotent and so those of $I+aA$ are all $1$s.

Comment: Can you please give me some more details on how you prove that?

Comment: let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,....\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A_{n\times n}$, then eigenvalues of $kA$ are  $k\lambda_1, k\lambda_2,....k\lambda_n$. And the eigenvalues of $I+kA$ are $1+k\lambda_1, 1+k\lambda_2,....1+k\lambda_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are given a *nilpotent* matrix $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ such that $\rm A^2 = O_n$. Let its Jordan decomposition be $\rm A = P J P^{-1}$. Since $\rm A^2 = O_n$, we have $\rm J^2 = O_n$, which allows us to conclude that all the eigenvalues of $\rm A$ are *zero*. Let $\gamma \in \mathbb R$. Hence, all the eigenvalues of $\mathrm I_n + \gamma \mathrm A$ are $1$ and, thus, $\mathrm I_n + \gamma \mathrm A$ is *invertible*.